# Can I mark builds by which iOS version the user has?

Tags: ios

Maybe this isn't even the correct question but I'm not quite sure how to ask this

Since Apple released the iOS 10 beta, I put it on my phone to test my app. Expectedly, it would crash and I was able to remedy the situation with a new build of my app on my computer.

When my users install iOS 10, they're going to have the same issues until I can get this new version to them.

My question is can I upload my new build to the App Store but only for iOS 10 users? And if not, would this build work for users with iOS 9 since it has the Swift 3 language in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I upload my new build to the App Store but only for iOS 10 users

Absolutely. Just edit the project and make 10.0 the Deployment Target. Done.

Comment: So say my current version is 1.5 and I upload this one as 1.6, my users below iOS 10 would only be able to go up to 1.5?

Comment: Correct. This is in fact what I do with all my apps; when a new version of iOS comes out, I create a new version of my app with a higher Deployment Target and thus abandon my users who don't update to the new version of iOS. Those users can only download the earlier version of my app. I _never_ aim at backwards compatibility. Many developers do, but I don't. To me, it's just not worth the trouble.